# Prove that we can divide a group of 90 people into 3 groups each with 30 people so that everyone has a friend in group

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification, probabilistic-method

> Prove that we can divide a group of 90 people into 3 groups each with 30 people so that each has a friend in group if each one has more than 30 friends. Friendships is a symmetric relation.

I tryed to think probabilistic.

Divide arbitrary group in 3 equal parts, so we can do that on $${1\over 6}{90\choose 30}{60\choose 30}$$ Let $D_i$ be an event $i$ has no friend in group. The number of such events is $$m_i = {1\over 2}{89-d_i\choose 29}{60\choose 30}$$ where $d_i$ is number of friends for $i$, so $$m_i\leq {1\over 2}{59\choose 29}{60\choose 30}$$ Now we have $$P(\bigcup D_i)\leq \sum _{i=1}^{90}P(D_i) \leq 90\cdot {3{59\choose 29}\over {90\choose 60}} <1$$
So the probability that $\bigcup D_i$ doesn't happend is more than $0$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this seems to me to be a correct application of the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality). In particular, you have shown that the probability of the event $(\lnot D_1)\lor (\lnot D_2)\lor\cdots\lor (\lnot D_{90})$ is strictly less than $1$. It follows that the probability of the event $\lnot\left((\lnot D_1)\lor (\lnot D_2)\lor\cdots\lor (\lnot D_{90})\right)\iff D_1\land D_2\land\cdots\land D_{90}$ is strictly greater than $0$. So among the sample space, i.e. the set of all partitions of the $90$ individuals into three equally-sized groups, there is at least one for which $D_1\land D_2\land\cdots\land D_{90}$, as desired.

Comment: Ok, but are the proabilites correctly calculated?

Comment: That is my actualy concern.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: You made a calculation or is it only a believe?

Comment: Come on Rafay, please do the calculation of probabilites for $D_i$, you don't need to do actual estimate, I just need $P(D_i)$.

Comment: Well, we want the number of (unordered) partitions such that a given person $p_i$ is with none of her friends. As you did, denote this number as $i\geq 30$. First, how many ways can we choose the $29$ remaining members of $p_i$'s group? We have $89-d_i$ options to place in $29$ slots, so the answer is $\tbinom{89-d_i}{29}$. As for the remaining $60$ people, the number of ways to split them into two groups of $30$ is $\tfrac{1}{2}\tbinom{60}{30}$ (where the $\tfrac{1}{2}$ accounts for the fact that choosing a group or choosing its complement give the same partition). So your computation is good

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I haven't seen too many probabilistic method problems on here, so I was intrigued. Also there's a very minor typo in that last comment of mine, it should say "denote this number as $d_i\geq 30$" :)